# How to Masquerade in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, internet

I'd like to share my internet connection. I've two eth cards installed. When I attempt what worked in the past the terminal say's eth0 does not exist. What's up? Is there a better method?

Comment: Now interface is not called `eth0`

Comment: Ubuntu used to use eth0 but a couple of years ago we switched to predictive naming. List the network names and see it is not eth0 but something like enp4s0f1 ;)

Comment: You can view available interfaces either via `ip addr` command or `ifconfig`, but first one is preferred nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Just use internal card ip addres

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.254.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

It works until reboot.

PS

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward should be enabled

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

You can uncomment in /etc/sysctl.conf to keep this after the system restart

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```